# Is there a job title for some of the responsibilities of an engineering director that doesn’t have reports?

Tags: job-change

We recently had a major reorganization at work.

I’m currently helping the head of engineering. He has put me  in charge of some of the duties of an engineering director/manager like:

- SDLC improvements.
- Recruitment and recruitment process improvements.
- Career path and role definitions.
- Define training programs.
- On boarding process for new engineers.
- Some incident management and resolution.

I don’t have direct reports and am not interested at the moment on having.

Does a job title for a role with these responsibilities and similar without reports?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps "lead engineer"?

Comment: What is you goal in defining a job title now? Do you want to include it on a CV to job-junt? In your email signature?... what was your original title before the restructuring

Comment: "Process manager" comes to mind from SDLC. HR fits the rest best, although your are likely expected to be doing it from a very technically-oriented viewpoint rather than a uniquely "people" POV.

Comment: Currently I have the director of engineering job title, I’m searching for a job title that reflect my current responsibilities, I could keep this title. I’m searching a new job title to avoid confusion within the organization.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need direct reports to have a managerial title.

We could give you suggestions, but you know your role best, so I would do some research on LinkedIn or job posting sites to see what titles are aligned with your responsibilities.

When you have several candidates for a title, discuss them with the head of engineering to make sure that his expectations align with yours.